# Unable to retrieve values from checkbox array

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, post, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes(array) as codes below:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Business" /> Business</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Public Affairs / Law" />Public Affairs / Law</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Medicine" />Medicine</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Literature / Writing / Journalism" />Literature / Writing / Journalism</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Technology" />Technology</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Engineering" />Engineering</label>
</div>
```

When the form submitted, I tried to retrieve the selected values by:

```
         print_r($_POST['major']);
```

it prints:

```
         Array ( [0] => [1] => )
```

It detecting two checkboxes are ticked but it somehow unable to retrieve the values out. What am I doing wrong?

=======================PHP snippets============================

```
require 'dbconnect.php';


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
                 if(isset($_POST['major'])){

                $top_majors = implode(',', $_POST['top_three_major']);

                echo $top_majors;
            }else{

                $top_majors = '-';

            }
}
```

=======================Solved============================

OK, I solved my problem. It was a stupid mistake that I try to clear the form fields when the browser was ready, thus, the checkbox values are reset before it able to POST.

Thank you guys for helping me! Especially Learner Student, I appreciate that! I hope I can vote you all up but too bad my reputation was far too low.

Thanks again.

Comment: You missed doublequotes for the name of third input

Comment: I accidentally deleted the double quotes when I edit the "name". It was there in my original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code. there were some quotes missing. after addign thos worked perfectly well.

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Business" /> Business</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Public Affairs / Law" />Public Affairs / Law</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Medicine" />Medicine</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Literature / Writing / Journalism" />Literature / Writing / Journalism</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name=major[] value="Technology" />Technology</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Engineering" />Engineering</label>
</div>
```

--PHP---

```
print_r($_POST['major']);
```

--out put-----

```
Array ( [0] => Medicine [1] => Literature / Writing / Journalism [2] => Technology )
```

Comment: The missing double quotes is due to my mistake when editing the name. It was there in my original code. It somehow unable to return the value. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: sorry i did not understood. can you please explain. is you $_POST not showing any value still if you check?

Comment: Yes, if I check two values and submit. It returns "Array ( [0] => [1] => )". It detecting two checkboxes checked but somehow the values are not pass through.

Comment: hmm seems intresting as It works for me. Please do one thing can you post full form code so i can see may be some issue with form code and i can run it with me here

Comment: Please check my first post there. It was quite a long form and I had shorten the codes, I hope I won't over-simplified. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for posting code. I have copied and pasted your form code and posted it on same page. It worked perfectly well. I mean I am getting all selected check box values. When you press you submit button and in php it does not display any values. you HTML form is ok please post you PHP code then bcz here id ont find any issue

Comment: Thanks for your help. I only posted the codes how I retrieves the checkbox values. I don't think others code will effects the result. Please let me know if I need to.

Comment: thanks for reply. your HTML code is working perfect. I tested it on my system. may be there is some issue with PHP code. If you want you can remove  your form code I have tested it.

Comment: I don't think is the PHP code problem. I even tried with simplest PHP get but still unable to get the values out. I think is the HTML codes problem. I will post all my HTML codes. Can you please check for me again?

Comment: yes..I just changed it to "major" here to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Medicine" />Medicine</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Literature / Writing / Journalism" />Literature / Writing / Journalism</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Technology" />Technology</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Engineering" />Engineering</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it is working now...

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Medicine"/>Medicine</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Literature / Writing / Journalism"/>Literature / Writing / Journalism</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Technology"/>Technology</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Engineering"/>Engineering</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In php write this code at same page because I write `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` in `action` mean submit form at same page just change the action if you want to.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST['major']);echo '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: The double quotes is originally there in my code but I accidentally deleted it when I try to post here. So, I don't think that is the reason. I still unable to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

it's working :

```
   <form action="" method="post" >
   <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Medicine" />Medicine</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Literature / Writing / Journalism" />Literature / Writing / Journalism</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Technology" />Technology</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="major[]" value="Engineering" />Engineering</label>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['major']))
print_r($_POST['major']);
?>
```

3th `name=major[]"` Just change to  `name="major[]"` Your Html syntax is wrong!!!

Comment: Thanks for reply. The missing double quotes is due to my mistake when editing the name. It was there in my original code. I don't think this is the reason (for my case) any idea why this happen? I tried to isolate the problem and it works perfectly but not my current codes.